# while generating image from array getting error

Tags: python-3.x

```
img_out.itemset[int(i),int(j)],int(b)
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Can anyone tell me, Why this error is occurring?

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('/home/god/Downloads/images/flower.png')
img_out = img.copy()
cv2.imshow('image',img)
height = img.shape[0]
width = img.shape[1]

gauss = (1.0/57)*np.array(
     [[0,1,2,1,0],
      [1,3,5,3,1],
      [2,5,9,5,2],
      [1,3,5,3,1],
      [0,1,2,1,0]])

sum(sum(gauss))
for i in np.arange(2,height-2):
for j in np.arange(2,width-2):
    sum = 0
for k in np.arange(-2,3):
    for l in np.arange(-2,3):
         a = img[i+k,j+l]
         p = gauss[2+k,2+l]
         sum = sum+(p+a)
b = sum
img_out.itemset[i,t(j)],int(b)
cv2.imshow('image',img_out)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Does anyone know what is wrong with this code? How to add the values of two arrays and put the modified array to build an image.

Comment: `img_out.itemset[i,t(j)]` -> `img_out.itemset(i,t(j))`. As a side note, `int(b)` on the same line does not do anything.

Comment: this line is causing the error .i donot know how to rephrase it.it is changing the image.how to write the code to change the array values and then displaying the image from the modified array

Comment: I showed you how to change it. Did you read my comment?

Comment: I get the error as below                                                                                                                                                
    img_out.itemset[i,t(j) -> img_out.itemset(i,t(j))
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: -> means replace one with the other

Comment: You also have major indentation issues. Please update your code in the question.

Comment: the other one gives this error :                                                                                            img_out.itemset(i,t(j))
NameError: name 't' is not defined

Comment: That's because you never defined it. But it's a different error.

Comment: t is to be defined as?

Comment: I have no idea. This is your code.